# how to access functions written in c/c++ into ruby script?

Tags: c++, c, ruby, linux

I have a ruby script. I need to access the functions written in c/c++ in my ruby script. Can any one tell me how to access these functions.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Other options are:

- [FFI](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki)
- without additional SW as described here: [pickaxe book](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ext_ruby.html)

Answer (score 1):

Ryan Davis has created a 'Hello, World!' C extension example for beginners:

https://github.com/zenspider/ruby-c-example

Answer (score 1):

You could also try [Rubyinline](https://github.com/seattlerb/rubyinline)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Ruby module that wraps your C/C++ functions using [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/).

Comment: Miguel thanks for support, is there any way without the use of software like SWING.

Comment: SWIG is the cleanest solution, but you have a number of other options. You could make an executable from your C functions, then invoke the executable from Ruby via a `system()` call, for example.